# jquery yes/no Dialog issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, confirm

Am developing web apps, when i try to validate, and submit the form like this its working fine.

```
                var res = confirm ("Are u want to continue?")
                if (res)
                {
                    var stra_validator = $("#form").validate(form_rule);
                    stra_validator.reset();
                    return stra_validator.form();

                }else{
                    $('#someID').focus();
                    return false;
                }
```

But when i try to use jQuery dialog, i used like this

```
                      var btns = {};
                      btns['Yes'] = function(){ 
                          $(this).dialog("close");

                          var stra_validator = $("#form").validate(form_rule);
                    stra_validator.reset();
                    return stra_validator.form();// continue the process 
                      };
                      btns['No'] = function(){ 
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                                     $('#someID').focus();
                    return false;
                      };
                      $("<div></div>").dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        title: 'Condition',
                        modal:true,
                        buttons:btns
                      });
```

its not getting proceed next step i mean not submitting. But if i click no it is focusing. what i did wrong here? please help me any one? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think $(this).dialog() is wrong in button context.

Try this:

```
var btns = {};
btns['Yes'] = function() {

  // Here you have to reference the real dialog
  $('#dialog').dialog("close");
  alert('come here');
  var stra_validator = $("#form").validate(form_rule);
  stra_validator.reset();

  return stra_validator.form();
  // continue the process
};
btns['No'] = function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog("close");
  $('#someID').focus();

  return false;
};

// Never created a div on the fly but it's working well and I just added an ID
$('<div id="dialog"></div>').dialog({
autoOpen : true,
title : 'Condition',
modal : true,
buttons : btns
});
```

Comment: Hey Bernhard,

  Thanks for your quick reply, when i use "id='dialog'" mentioned, alert coming but still same issue.

 when i use  $('#dialog').dialog("close") like this even dialog box also not closing.

Thanks